# Yii redirect is not working correctly in server

Tags: php, redirect, yii

After login I'm trying to redirect the user based on their user role to their specified page. I tried redirect and header but both is not working for me in the server.

I tried,

```
$this->redirect('dashboard/profile');  
$this->redirect(array('dashboard/profile'));  
header('Location: dashboard/profile');
```

I'm getting this error

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/deheal/public_html/dev/index.php:2)
```

This all working perfectly in the local but not in the server please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is happening on execution of above rediects. Is it redirecting to some other url or not redirecting at all?

Comment: i'm getting this error  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/deheal/public_html/dev/index.php:2)

Comment: when you do a redirect, there should not be any output to the browser before the redirect. That is what causes this error. See my answer below to find pointers to solve it

Comment: answer just accepted, no upvote? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use redirection somewhere in the middle of the page, you need to make sure there is no output to the browser before the redirection. You can use ob_start() function to buffer the output before sending it to browser so that headers are not sent before you do the redirection

```
ob_start() .....starts buffering the output
ob_flush()......flushes out the output that was buffered
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `/` before `URL`

```
$this->redirect('/dashboard/profile');
```

You cannot use `header()` once text has been output to the browser. As your `header.php` include presumably outputs HTML, header() cannot be used.

You can solve this in a couple ways:

Move the `if statement` above the header include (this won't work, as you've indicated in comments that `header.php` sets the `uid session` and other `vital stuff`).
Call `ob_start()` at the top of the script to buffer the output.

As per your updated question you can use `window.location` instead of `header("location:URL")`

```
<?php 
//Php code here
?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location= 'dashboard/profile';
        </script>
<?php 
//Php code here
?>
```

Comment: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/deheal/public_html/dev/index.php:2)`

Comment: The redirection is in the controller login function, can i user `ob_start();` in that function itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform redirection by **javascript**, Because you **cannot modify header** after rendering. But this function can do that. Just call it and you will be redirected to page you want to.

```
<?php
function redirect_url($url)
{
?>
<script>
document.title="Loading";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML="Please Wait.....";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML+='<img src="../../images/loading_2.gif" style="height:20px;width:20px;"/>';
window.location.href="<?php
echo $url;
?>";
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem before. It was showing an header error on my controller.

> Copy all your codes in your controller, and create new file, paste
>   your code and save with same name.

It must help.